# How do I define name 'feildNames1'?

Tags: python, nameerror, easygui

**I've been googling and I cannot find a solution. Would someone please share a working example?**

```
import easygui

#Multi Enter Box
fieldNames1= ['Situation:(Example: Waiting for a friend who is late.)','Thoughts:(EXAMPLE: My friend Bob is always late!)','Emotions:(EXAMPLE: Mad & Stressed)','Behavior:(EXAMPLE: Arguing with family)']


#Write to file
file = open('Log.txt', 'a')
file.write(feildNames1)
file.close()
```

**This is the error that I'm struggling with:**

> ```
> file.write(repr(feildNames1))
> NameError: name 'feildNames1' is not defined
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a spelling error.

You're setting the `fieldNames1` variable, but calling `repr()` on `feildNames1`. Note the placement of the `e` and `i`